# WAMP Mysql service start up problem

Tags: php

i have installed wamp but my mysql service is not starting.
i got an error in mysql log file. It says "The first specified data file .\ibdata1 did not exist:"

Answer (score 1):

Erase everything in the MySQL `data/` folder - except `mysql/` and `test/` then restart.